# How can I click on drawer home button in my application using Robotium

Tags: android, testing, junit, robotium

How can i click on my drawer home button using Robotium?

So far I have tried:

```
public void test5(){    
    solo.setNavigationDrawer(Solo.OPENED);

}
public void test5(){    
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check on main activity", MainActivity.class);
    solo.clickOnButton("ClimbCro"); 
}
public void test5(){        
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Provjera login aktivnosti", LoginActivity.class);   
    solo.clickOnActionBarHomeButton();
    solo.clickOnActionBarItem(2);
}
```

Also if the drawer can be opened how can I click an item on it?

[Screenshot of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2hlp.jpg)